# Rasterizing a Layer with current adjustment layers?

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, photos

Right now I have 52 layers for 52 playing cards. They are all a little off hue. I want to apply a hue saturation that affects them all. I then want to rasterize them to include the hue adjustment so I can then remove the hue adjustment from the global adjustment layers.

I tried taking one of the card layers and making a smart object then rasterizing but this had no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options if you have layers like this:

```
ADJUSTMENT LAYER
________________
CARD 1
________________
CARD 2
________________
CARD 3
________________
etc
```

1. Make visible only CARD 1+ADJUSTMENT LAYER (make background hidden as well) and press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+E. After that, hide the newly created layer and CARD 1 layer. Then you make visible only CARD 2+ADJUSTMENT LAYER and repeat the process, and so on.
2. Remember the settings from your adjustment layer and then remove it. Now click each CARD layer and press CTRL+U, input the remembered settings, click OK. This way you add the adjustment to each layer separately.
3. Create a droplet that adds a desired adjustment, export your layers as separate files with "Export layers to files..." script and just drag and drop all those new files on your droplet. That is the way that I'd do it.

Hope that helps...